# Difference between strings and char arrays in objective c in #import statements

Tags: objective-c, c, string, import, char

I recently noticed this while working on an app- why is it that when you import a file you use

```
#import "SomeFile.h"
```

but when you are manipulating a string you use the @ symbol before the string, such as

```
NSLog(@"Hello World");
```

I know these two are not interchangeable, so is there a specific reason the `#import` directive *doesn't* take a type of string? There must be some history/a good reason behind this. Maybe. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `#import` statement is a **preprocessor macro** that is used when the **compiler** compiles your code. It makes sure that the file you are going to import is actually added to the source file you're compiling.

The compiler takes its own type of string to find the file. When not using the `"` you are actually talking about a `C` type string, or `char[]`.
When using the `@""` directive, you are actually talking about an object of type `NSString`, which is in the end also, a 0-terminated array of chars.

So basically, they're both strings. But the `@""` directive is used in Objective C to denote a string object, and the standard `" "` notation is used for lower level languages' string types.

Answer (score 2):

Its because `#import` is a preprocessor macro, that is compiled before the objc runtime is even a part of the picture. All import is is a wrapper around `#include` that makes sure you don't include the same file twice.